# Multi Select dropdown not working

Tags: php, jquery-select2, dropdown, multi-select

Need help in a school project!!

I am developing a web application using html/php, ssms and a bit of javascript.  I have made a form and the connection is working too.
The front end of multi select dropdown is working but it is not saving data into the database. 
While the other input fields are getting saved but the multi select isn't. I am not sure what is wrong. 
Can anyone help?

```
<html>

    <body>

        <div class="container" >
            <form class="cmxform" id="Form">
                <div id="FormResult" class="hide" role="alert">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <div id="resultFormContent"></div>
                </div>  
                <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                    * Indicates required field
                </div>
                <div class="form-row">
                    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                        <label for="fName">First Name *</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fName" name="fName" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                        <label for="mName">Middle Name</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="mName" name="mName" >
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                        <label for="lName">Last Name *</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lName" name="lName" required>
                    </div>
                </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                    <label for="race">Race</label>
                    <select class="form-control" multiple data-actions-box="true" id="race" name="race">
                        <option value="White">White</option>
                        <option value="Black">Black</option>
                        <option value="American Indian or Alaska Native ">American Indian or Alaska Native</option>
                        <option value="Asian">Asian</option>
                        <option value="Native Hawaiian or Other Pacific Islander">Native Hawaiian or Other Pacific Islander</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                    <label for="gender">Gender Identity</label>
                    <select name="gender" class="form-control" id="gender"  >
                    <option value="">Select...</option>
                        <option value="Male/Man">Male/Man</option>
                        <option value="Female/Woman">Female/Woman</option>
                        <option value="TransMale/TransMan">TransMale/TransMan</option>
                        <option value="TransFemale/TransWoman">TransFemale/TransWoman</option>
                        <option value="GenderQueer/Gender nonconforming">GenderQueer/Gender nonconforming</option>
                        <option value="Something Else">Something Else</option>
                        <option value="Decline to answer">Decline to answer</option>
                </select>
                </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                    <label for="comments">Questions/Comments:</label>
                    <textarea class="form-control" id="comments" name="comments" rows="3"></textarea>
                </div>

                <!--                <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LfvDD8UAAAAAK8yM3oUhRmEGnQFrd49cLgJ_ypn" data-callback="captchaEvent"></div>-->
                <br>
                <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                    <button class="btn btn-info btn-primary" id="registerSubmit" type="submit">Submit</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

functions

```
require_once 'queries.php';

$fName = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "fName");
$lName = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "lName");
$mName = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "mName");  
$race = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "race");
$gender = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "gender");
$comments = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "comments");


switch ($switch) {
        case 'add':
            echo Queries::addInfo($fName, $lName, $mName, $race,$gender,$comments);
        break;
    }

?>
```

queries

```
<?php

require_once 'db_connection.php';

class Queries {
public static function addInfo($fName,  $lName, $mName, $race,$gender,$comments ) {
        $conn = DB::databaseConnection();
        $conn->beginTransaction();
$sql = "INSERT INTO dbo.tracker (First_Name,  Last_Name, Middle_Name, Race, Gender Identity, Comments) VALUES (:fName, :lName, :mName, :race,:gender,:comments )";

$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bindParam(':fName', $fName);
        $stmt->bindParam(':lName', $lName);
        $stmt->bindParam(':mName', $mName);
        $stmt->bindParam(':race', $race);
        $stmt->bindParam(':gender', $gender);
       $stmt->bindParam(':comments', $comments);
        if ($stmt->execute()) {
            $conn->commit();
            return true;
        } else {
            $conn->rollback();
            return false;
        }
    }

    }
```

js

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#race").select2({
        maximumSelectionLength: 5,
        placeholder: "Select all that apply...",
        allowClear: true
    });

$("#Form").submit(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: 'functions/form-functions.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {"fName": $('#fName').val(), "lName": $('#lName').val(), "mName": $('#mName').val(), 
                  "race": $('#race').val(),  "gender": $('#gender').val(), "comments": $('#comments').val(), "switch": "add"},
            dataType: "json",
            success: function () {
                $('#Form').trigger('reset');
                resultAlert('#FormResult', '#resultFormContent', '<strong>Your data was succefully saved!</strong>', 'alert-success');
            }, error: function () {
                resultAlert('#FormResult', '#resultFormContent', '<strong>Error! Your data was not saved!</strong>', 'alert-danger');
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: You're passing an array to be saved in a database row/column intersection. That's not really allowed in relational databases.

Comment: @apokryfos Hey can you tell me how do I correct it?

Comment: You can either remove `race` from your table and create a relationship that relates `tracker` with one or more races. Or don't do multi-select and just populate the select with all permutations (there will be 31 for combinations for 5 choices)